# Service worker is not working in offline mode when angular project is deployed on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have created an angular (angular 7) application and then added `ng add @angular/pwa` angular PWA library to it. 
Now after building it using `ng build --prod` and then serving the application to `localhost:8080` via node's `http-server`, my application is running fine in  offline mode in localhost.

But when i build the same application using `ng build --prod --base-href /myProject/` to deploy on IIS, application is working fine but when switch to `offline mode` using chrome's developer tool, i am getting error `HTTP Error 504`.

Please suggest what is causing this strange behavior and how to fix it.

Comment: refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393706/9444169

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try by omitting "--base-href /myProject/" while building

Comment: After omtting this command, i won't be able to deploy the project in a sub-folder in IIS.

Comment: outcome of this command will be "dist" folder in root, simply copy paste the content of it to your IIS folder, this should work,

Comment: I have tried it, but no luck. I suspect it has something to do the way angular application is build.

Comment: try alter your index.html file
```--base-href=./ ```